# Rounds in a card game

Tags: c++, playing-cards

The game has 4 players.Each player takes turns being the card czar after the round ends. I've stored cards assigned to each player in vectors. How would i create rounds in this game? Would i create a loop in the main function to run 4 times and clear the vectors and call my functions within the loop?
Here is my main function:

```
int main()
{   

vector<string> player;
vector<string> blackCards;
vector<string> whiteCards;
vector<string> CardCzar;
vector<string> player2;
vector<string> player3;
vector<string> player4;
int sz = 0;
int i = 0;
string n;

        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {   cout<<"Enter name for player"<<" "<< i+1 << " : "<<" ";
         cin>> n;
         player.push_back(n);
    }

BlackCards(blackCards);
WhiteCards(whiteCards);
order(player);
sz = player.size();
cout<<" "<<endl;
cout<<"*"<<player[sz - 4]<<" , you are the card czar for this round *"  <<endl;

assign_bcards(blackCards , CardCzar, player);
assign_wcards(whiteCards, player2, player3, player4, player);





    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What specifically does not work in your current approach?

Comment: The game will run for one round. what i need is for the round to end so player 2 will become the card czar and the rest will get the regular white cards. This should repeat until all 4 players have been the card czar.

Comment: Rename your current `main()` to `game_round()`. Then write a new `main()` which calls that in a loop.

Comment: @Darklord098 In C++, functions can't contain other normal functions. Both functions I suggest should be normal "top-level" functions. I mean literally what I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make rounds you could have a loop with a circular indicator that hits every player in order. An easy numerical way to do this is

```
int currentCzar = 0;
while(gameIsNotOver)
{
  *Do game stuff*
  currentCzar = (currentCzar+1) % numPlayers;
}
```

Since currentCzar is always less than numPlayers

```
(currentCzar+1) % numPlayers;
```

will always return a values c where

```
0 <= c <= numPlayers-1
```

Then just have some other flag tell you when to stop playing like a win condition. Also numPlayers would be the size of the array.

EDIT:
You might also want to change the way you structre your data. Maybe by making a player a class or struct so that you can have something like

```
class Player{
   vector<string> whiteCards;
   vector<string> wonBlackCardsl
   //Boilerplate class code
}
vector<Player> players;
*assign cards and create players*
int currentCzar = 0;
while(gameIsNotOver)
{
   *Do game stuff*
    //Have players[currentCzar] choose a black card
    //Have every other player put down a white card
    currentCzar = (currentCzar+1) % numPlayers;
}
```

Then you could couple the players to their hands in a much more direct way

Comment: by 'game stuff' do you mean my function calls? And this loop would be in the main function?

Comment: The actual mechanics of the game, like you know who the current Czar is and then you can decide who chooses the black card, then you can have everyone else put down their white card down and so on. That counter will allow you to iterate through the players without having to worry about index out of bounds error. So that would give you your round mechanism. *Game stuff* would be everything that happens in a round besides determining who is the next czar

Comment: I'd rather not use classes. I have a general concept of OOP but it wasn't in my CS100 course. But just for the heck of it, will the way i suggested not work? To create a loop in the main function(maybe like the one you suggested) that'll contain all my function calls and then at the end clear all the vectors for each player?

Comment: Yes that could work but it seems a little messy, but I'm not completely certain of the game play you are going for is this like *Cards against Humanity*?

Comment: It is cards against humanity yes. And messy is just fine haha. Like i said I'm doing a  CS100 course.

Comment: Then yes your original concept of looping and calling the functions inside the loop should work.